# Remove margin from last item in row

Tags: css

I have 3 columns and 3 rows of div elements.

What is the best way to remove the right margin from every third item using CSS?

Comment: nth-child(3) doesn't work on all browsers...

Comment: Could you please post the html?

Comment: I think that IE6,7,8 are history...

Answer (score 2):

`:nth-child(3n)` will select every third item. Here's an example with an unordered list: http://jsfiddle.net/894p6/.

It's unsupported in IE8 or lower though. You can use jQuery selectors for it which will get over that though if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:nth-child`

```
div:nth-child(3n+3) {  
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Have a look at this link, very helpful: http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Answer (score -2):

you can add a custom class for your third item with margin right set to 0 px, but still you'll have to use something dynamic (if your rows can vary) to apply the stile.

for dynamic i mean something like an if statement detecting if the item is the third or not

Comment: can i please know why i got a downvote? it's not a wrong answer at all.

Comment: Did you just downvote all other answers because your has been downvoted?

Comment: nope, just one, why? i'm just asking, btw, why a common practice like having a class for a specific item, based on its position inside a "loop", is been downvoted here.